# Why I get quotes in the output of yaml file if I use exclamation mark?

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I creating a yaml file with name main.yaml but I want output as follows:

```
# example
Name:
  Job: abcd
  Addresss: xyz
  client_id: 641
test: !include test.yaml  # new key
```

I don’t want quotes in the output. So how to prevent the quotes from appearing in the output?

------------------------------code----------

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import SingleQuotedScalarString, DoubleQuotedScalarString

inp = """\
# example
Name:
  Job: abcd
  Addresss: xyz
  client_id: 641
"""

opath2= Path('main.yaml')

with YAML(output=opath2) as yaml:
  yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
  code = yaml.load(inp)
  code.insert(1, 'test', '!include test.yaml', comment="new key")
  yaml.dump(code, sys.stdout)
```

------------------------------output------------------------------

```
# example
Name:
  Job: abcd
  Addresss: xyz
  client_id: 641
test: '!include test.yaml'  # new key
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don’t want quotes in the output. So how to prevent the quotes from appearing in the output?

In YAML, strings can only be unquoted if they don't have another meaning. `124` is a number, not a string. `true` is a boolean, not a string. `!foo` denotes a [tag](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2761292), not a string. Thus, if you want an unquoted string that starts with an exclamation mark, you are out of luck, can't do it in YAML.

If you actually want to insert a tag, as deceze thinks, you need to do some work. The easiest is to actually implement a class that will be represented so.

```
import ruamel

class Include(ruamel.yaml.YAMLObject):
    yaml_constructor = ruamel.yaml.RoundTripConstructor
    yaml_representer = ruamel.yaml.RoundTripRepresenter
    yaml_tag = '!include'

    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, loader, node):
        return cls(loader.construct_scalar(node))

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, dumper, data):
        if isinstance(data.file, ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.ScalarString):
            style = data.file.style  # ruamel.yaml>0.15.8
        else:
            style = None
        return dumper.represent_scalar(cls.yaml_tag, data.file, style=style)
```

(Shamelessly copied from `ruamel/_test/test_add_xxx.py`.) Then you can do

```
code.insert(1, 'test', Include('test.yaml'), comment="new key")
```

Comment: I suspect OP may *want* the special meaning there and wonders how to create a tag programatically…

Comment: @Amadan Thanks, your code worked!
It was really helpful.