# Exclamation mark as a value

Tags: yaml, ruamel.yaml

A follow up question after [Inconsistent list indent in Ansible/Yaml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74551635/inconsistent-list-indent-in-ansible-yaml-file). The Ansible hardening task part below includes `shell` to include commands and the exclamation mark is used there for negating the value. Due to the special usage of exclamation mark in YAML specs, the mark is removed and the shell command negation part is omitted.

```
# R-238374 UBTU-20-010454
- name: check if ufw.service is installed
  shell: ! systemctl list-unit-files | grep "^ufw.service[ \t]\+"
  changed_when: False
  check_mode: no
  register: result
  failed_when: result.rc > 1
- name: stigrule_238374_ufw_active
  service:
    name: ufw.service
    enabled: "{{ ubuntu2004STIG_stigrule_238374_ufw_active_Enabled }}"
  when:
    - ubuntu2004STIG_stigrule_238374_Manage
    - result.rc == 0
# R-238374 UBTU-20-010454
- name: check if ufw.service is installed
  shell: ! systemctl list-unit-files | grep "^ufw.service[ \t]\+"
  changed_when: False
  check_mode: no
  register: result
  failed_when: result.rc > 1
- name: stigrule_238374_ufw_start
  service:
    name: ufw.service
    state: "{{ ubuntu2004STIG_stigrule_238374_ufw_start_State }}"
  when:
    - ubuntu2004STIG_stigrule_238374_Manage
    - result.rc == 0
```

So the `shell: ! systemctl list-unit-files | grep "^ufw.service[ \t]\+"` becomes `shell: systemctl list-unit-files | grep "^ufw.service[ \t]\+"` .

What can be done to leave the exclamation mark as is?

P.S: The solutions below about tags and custom constructors did not work:

- [Unable to add list member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56295947/unable-to-add-list-member/56296425#56296425)
- [Python ruamel.yaml dumps tags with quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50996060/python-ruamel-yaml-dumps-tags-with-quotes/50999023#50999023)
- [Why I get quotes in the output of yaml file if I use exclamation mark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53612637/why-i-get-quotes-in-the-output-of-yaml-file-if-i-use-exclamation-mark)

Comment: That is a tag without a name ( you can check [here](http://ben-kiki.org/ypaste/cgi-bin/ypaste.pl) ). I don't know what ansible uses as a YAML library to load that and have access to the ! (or its existence) but but ruamel.yaml (and e.g PyYAML) do not. Put the whole value in single quotes is what you should do.

Comment: Since `ruamel.yaml` omits the single exclamation mark during load, I need to preprocess the text then. That feels like a hack or workaround but since the specs require it, it is the only solution then. Thanks for the information.